# What will be more expensive? Passing additional parameters from the frontend or processing 'few' parameters at the Backend?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, backend, web-frontend

I need some insight into evaluating the expense of frontend and backend operation for a similar task.

In my angular Controller, I am creating a JSON that will have about 20 keys. 
Example: `{'A':'allergy','B':'dog' ...and so on}`
This JSON is then passed to say, abc.js(written in Node) which processes  it.

I have a requirement for generating the singular and plural form of the passed keys in the JSON. I can modify the JSON in my controller which would be something like this.
`{'A':{'name':'allergy', 'singular':'Allergy', 'plural':'Allergies'},'B':{name:'dog', 'singular':'Dog', 'plural':'Dogs'} ...and so on }` 
I can also process the original 20 parameters at the backend to get the singular and plural form.  Generating the plural at backend will involve amongst others, few string operations.

Which one should I prefer considering efficiency? Passing additional parameters from frontend or processing them at the backend to generate the singular and plural forms? Moreover which approach is generally preferred for above similar Use Cases?

As per my understanding pass as few parameters as possible from frontend and do most of the heavy lifting at the backend.

Comment: What do you mean with `I can either add 40 new keys(20*2) or process the original 20 parameters`? What are the 40 new keys? Show two examples of the data you would pass one with the the original 20 and one with the 40 new.

Comment: In this kind of situation, in my opinion, I would assume if the situation becomes 2,000 parameters. To me this kind of bandwidth costs is unnecessary, and more important is that it gives unnecessary burden to the performance of front-end.

Comment: @t.niese I have updated the question. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: That depends on different factors. Let's assume that bandwidth is not a problem. How important is it that the singular/plural form you receive is correct, e.g. would it result into a problem if I use you application and send modified request to your API like this: `{'A':{'name':'allergy', 'singular':'Gold', 'plural':'Silver'},'B':{name:'dog', 'singular':'Cat', 'plural':'Cats'} ...and so on }`? If this is causing a problem, that is not just affecting me, then you have to create the `singular` and `plural` on the server side.

Comment: @Carr That's too simplified. First of all it can be questioned if the number of operation required to create those strings on the client is significantly large compared to the operations angular does for the gui itself. With regard to scalability, it can be an important consideration between bandwidth, outsourcing calculations to the client or buying more server performance. But much more crucial is how important the correctness of the data you get is.

Comment: @t.niese As I mentioned `In my angular Controller, I am creating a JSON that will have about 20 keys` User can't modify and send some random input.

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar If the data is send from my browser to your server, then I will be able to modify that data, and you must assume that some one sends some malicious data. In the developer tools of the browser I can monitor all request that are done, and I can always issue a new request that is slightly modified. And I can intercept and modify a request at any time with an extension. You **always** have to do a sanity check on the data you receive from the client.

Comment: @t.niese I agree.  By going through all your comments this is my understanding. If bandwidth and data integrity is not an issue send from frontend. But if Data Integrity is necessary always generate such at back end irrespective of bandwidth cost differences. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per my understanding pass as few parameters as possible from frontend and do most of the heavy lifting at the backend.

Not really, you should plan out what is necessarily required to be processed in the back end and what should be done in the front-end. Most of the  heavy-lifting in certain cases is passed on the to client as their computer isn't really working hard rendering a traditional web page. Another factor to consider is what necessarily must be hidden you don't want company secret algorithms on the front end. This JSON lookup is a trivial task which will put very little stress on the server so as @Carr mentions in the comments here as it is obvious this dictionary may grow to 1,000 bandwidth is a more important concern.

Also, like t.niese mentions it also depends on security and reliability  for example if you're evaluating if a password matches the security standard on the client only, some one can easily strip that layer off and bypass your standard.

In general most of the processing work which is not secretive can given to client, this will make servers efficient keeping the cost of operation low, but again common sense applies here you can not give the client so much to process that their fan starts making noises like a tractor.

Comment: The first consideration is: Do I have to rely on the accuracy of the data? And the client can cause damage if it sends data that is not correct. Only when this has been clarified you can think about the other factors.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, absolutely will add that in.

Comment: @t.niese question was prioritizing performance but this is definitely the most important consideration.

Comment: @t.niese  You can rely on the accuracy of data. User can't modify the JSON. The JSON is generated based on business logic from user inputs(selection, click events and so on).

Comment: @user3621843 I am prioritizing performance because accuracy will never be an issue.

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar the USer can for sure modify the JSON. The user could e.g. set a break point before the data is send, and then modify it there.